# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES); Can't reset password

Tags: mysql, mariadb

As it says in the title; when I do `mysql`, it says `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.
I tried doing `mysql -u root -p`, it says the same thing.
So I wanted to reset my password with `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` and when I do, this is showing:

> root@xx:~# 200315 17:45:56 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
>
> 200315 17:45:56 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

and when I do `mysql -u root`, it still says `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` and it quits `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`.

System is Nginx
And DB is MariaDB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `mysqld_safe` commands did not work.

It might be helpful stopping mysqld (like `sudo service mysqld stop` or `sudo stop systemctl mysql`) before the `mysqld_safe` command.